# Change the capital letter B in svg image but keep the letter B as letter for Google

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, svg, fonts

I may have a difficult and complicated question. A logo has recently been developed for us and the letter "B" is a unique letter B. This letter B has its own unique look, but we would like to use it for H1 titles on different pages. The reason we want to do this this way is to reflect our corporate identity on our website.

However, SEO is also very important for our website and we want Google to be able to read the H1 properly and therefore read the letter "B" as B and not see an image or SVG.

Is there a possibility to show this unique letter B that has been designed, but also leave the H1 title good for SEO.

Comment: make the B a font, then write the logo as B and display the B using your custom font.

Comment: @RobertLongson, So when I make the B as a font and create CSS to display that B as first letter of our H1 tags that should do the trick?

Comment: should do, yes.

Comment: see: [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)